How to configure vscode to start taking input in output panel
Why vscode's output panel doesn't take input. Is it read only?
I am not talking about the integrated terminal window , and also not about code-runner extension
Vscode's Output panel looks fast and updates infos fast.
I have already tried code-runner's every setting, nothing worked out.

The clue is in the name, its and output panel, its faster than the terminal because it's not a terminal, its just a text box. If you need a terminal, use the terminal

I'm not sure why you're surprised that the output panel does not accept input and cannot be configured to do so. Is there a specific reason you don't want to use the built-in terminal? More particularly, what are you trying to do that you feel like you can't accomplish in VS Code as-is?

@JRiggles The built-in terminal works fine for me, and simple programs like Hello World run quickly in the output panel. However, I can't provide input for user input programs in the output panel. I tried using the Code Runner extension to run programs in the terminal, which allows for input, but my computer lags. The output panel runs smoothly, though.
Btw thanks for giving time for my question

A basic console app really shouldn’t cause lag, but without seeing a [mre] it’s hard to say what’s causing performance issues, if anything. Remember: you can [edit] your question at any time.

Go to settings search run code configuration and enable "Run in terminal" & "save file before run"
